# I do not understand how a Natural value(parameter) works

Tags: haskell

I do not understand why "logistic0" function doesn't need an argument when implemented, and why a Natural value is not necessary to be passed as an argument at "logistic" function. Also, it's time to be calculated depends on the ex1 value, why ?

````
logistic :: Num a => a -> a -> Natural -> a
logistic rate start = f
  where
    f 0 = start
    f n = rate * f (n - 1) * (1 - f (n - 1)) 

logistic0 :: Fractional a => Natural -> a
logistic0 = logistic 3.741 0.00079

ex1 :: Natural
ex1 = 10000

logistic0 ex1
```
````

Answer (score 5):

This is partial application at work.

- `logistic` is a function that takes three arguments.
- `logistic 3.741` is a function that takes two arguments, since the first one was provided.
- `logistic 3.741 0.00079` is a function that takes one argument, since the first and second ones were provided.

In other words, the definition

```
logistic0 = logistic 3.741 0.00079
```

is equivalent, by eta-equivalence, to

```
logistic0 x = logistic 3.741 0.00079 x
```